# GCM is not working for to many device tokens ( > 800 )

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

A few days ago the push notification for Android devices was working fine because I had around 1000 device tokens so far in my database, but today it's not working because it's reached to around 1500 device tokens. I'm getting `java.io.IOException` on the server side.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1491)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1485)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:363)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:261)
    at com.orange.server.ws.androidpns.androidPNHandler.run(androidPNHandler.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:362)
    ... 2 more
```

I checked for one device token it worked fine but when there are to many device tokens (>800) in my database table I'm getting this above exception. Here is my server code for GCM.

```
Sender sender = new Sender("SENDER-ID");
AndroidPNSEntityHandler androidPNSEntityHandler = new AndroidPNSEntityHandler();
ArrayList<String> androidDeviceIds = androidPNSEntityHandler.getList();

/* I checked by adding only one device token to this arraylist like
this **androidDeviceIds.add("Android-Device-Token");**
It worked fine...
*/

if(androidDeviceIds.size() != 0)
{
    String title;
    if(!isOrangeCall)
        title = "title";
    else
        title = "oTitle";

    Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .collapseKey(pnsCollapseKey)
                .timeToLive(86400)
                .addData(title,msgTitle)
                .addData("content",msgContent)
                .build();
    try
    {
        MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, androidDeviceIds, 5);
        if (result.getResults() != null) 
        {
            int failureMsgs = result.getFailure();
            int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
            List<Result> multicastResults = result.getResults();
            Boolean flag =true;
            int total;
            if(failureMsgs != 0 || canonicalRegId != 0)
            {

                for(total = 0;flag;total++)
                {
                    if(canonicalRegId != 0)
                    {
                        String tempCanId = multicastResults.get(total).getCanonicalRegistrationId(); 
                        if( tempCanId != null)
                        {
                            if(androidPNSEntityHandler.deleteDuplicate(androidDeviceIds.get(total), tempCanId))
                                canonicalRegId--;
                        }
                    }
                    if(failureMsgs != 0)
                    {
                        if(multicastResults.get(total).getErrorCodeName().equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED))
                        {
                            if(androidPNSEntityHandler.deleteUid(androidDeviceIds.get(total)));
                            failureMsgs--;
                        }
                    }
                    if(canonicalRegId == 0 && failureMsgs == 0)
                        flag = false;
                }

            }

        }

    }catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (InvalidRequestException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (java.io.IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please guide me in resolving this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html)  make it quite clear that 1000 is the limit:

> registration_ids
>
> A string array with the list of devices (registration IDs) receiving
>   the message. It must contain at least 1 **and at most 1000**
>   registration IDs. To send a multicast message, you must use JSON. For
>   sending a single message to a single device, you could use a JSON
>   object with just 1 registration id, or plain text (see below).
>   Required.